# Reference request for unknown mathematical constant

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Below is a plot of

$$\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{x}x\ (\mathbb{mod}\  n)-\dfrac{x}{5.6325}$$

[image]

where $5.6325$ is very close to whatever the constant actually is. Does anyone know what this constant might be?

## Update

Thanks to Hagen von Eitzen's answer & Michael Stocker's comment, it seems that

$$\dfrac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{x}x\ (\mathbb{mod}\  n)-x\left(1-\dfrac{\pi^2}{12}\right)+\dfrac{1}{\pi}$$

stays remarkably tightly bounded. Is there any documentation anywhere about these bounds?

*Note: the $+\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ is not stated in Hagen von Eitzen's answer - purely conjectured at this point.*

[image]

Comment: "if it holds"??? There is no equation here, how can it "hold" for anything?

Comment: @barakmanos that its stays within a limit: $\pm 2$, or whatever it is. Was implied in the plot.

Comment: For which values of $x$ have you asserted that?

Comment: @barakmanos for the ones given in the plot, since I don't know what the constant is.

Comment: The "$\ldots+\frac1\pi$" in the Update is not immediately from my answer - but it seems a feasible result. To get it, one should average over $x$ - have fun

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen no, will update - but it does seem reasonable. Thanks!!

Comment: I feel like Flajolet has studied sums like this, and I feel like it might have shown up in either Concrete Mathematics or The Art Of Computer Programming; I particularly recommend digging into vol. 1 of the latter.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks - I will have a check :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $n>\frac12 x$, the summand is $x-n$, so these contribute $\approx \sum_{k=0}^{x/2}k\approx \frac18x^2$ to the sum.

For $\frac12x\ge n>\frac13x$, the summand is $x-2n$, so these contribute $\approx\sum_{k=0}^{x/6} 2k$ or $\approx\sum_{k=0}^{x/6} (2k+1)$, at any rate this is $\frac1{36}x^2+O(x)$.

More generally, for large enough $x$ and if $\frac1mx\ge n>\frac1{m+1}x$ with $m\ll x$ (say, $m\le \sqrt x$), the contribution is essentially (i.e. up to $O(x)$) the sum of all multiples of $m$ that are $<\frac x{m+1}$, so $\frac1{2m(m+1)^2}x^2+O(x)$.
On the other hand, if we cannot achieve $m\le\sqrt x$, then $n\le \sqrt x$, and those $n$ contribute at most ${\sqrt x\choose 2}\approx \frac 12x$.
Thus if we divide the sum by $x^2$, we are left with something like 
$$\tag1\frac{\sum_{n=0}^xx\bmod n}{x^2} =\sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt x}\frac1{2m(m+1)^2}+O(x^{-1/2}).$$
While this does not recognize your number "by name", it simpifies its numerical approximation:
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2m(m+1)^2}\approx 0.17753296657\ldots \approx \frac1{5.6327566\ldots}
$$

Thanks to *Michael Stocker*'s comment we know the exact value: 
$$1-\frac{\pi^2}{12} $$
(in fact, we somewhat recognize the well-known $\sum \frac1{m^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$, and *ypercube* noticed how to arrive at the result via $\frac1{m(m+1)^2}=\underbrace{\frac1m-\frac1{m+1}}_{\text{telescope}}-\frac1{(m+1)^2}$). Now all that remains is to get a better grip on the Big-Oh' I allowed to enter into the calculation ... 
Indeed, the OP's observation suggests that 
$$\tag2\frac{\sum_{n=0}^xx\bmod n}{x^2} =1-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+O(x^{-1})$$
and the worse estimate in $(1)$ cannot come from the incomplete series alone.

Comment: great! thank you! will have a read through now.

Comment: do you know any bounds for the sum? It seems remarkably regular.

Comment: Maple tells me that the sum is $1-\frac{1}{12}·\pi^2 = \frac{1}{\frac{12}{12-\pi^2}}$

Comment: Using $\frac{1}{m(m+1)^2} = \frac{1}{m} - \frac{1}{m+1} - \frac{1}{(m+1)^2}$

Comment: Maple is a math software. I thought there was an easy way like the one you get using ypercubes hint, but I was just lazy and let the software tell me :P

Comment: It's worth nothing that the tail of the incomplete series contributes about $1/x$ (with an error of probably $O(x^{-3/2})$), by comparison to the integral.